Should I be pruning my 1 year old thornless Honey Locust?
I have a 1 year old thornless Honey Locust.
The branches seem to be going faster the the trunk and I don't know if I need to cut them back.   (I read you are only supposed to cut trees 2 years are older but I'm worried that the tree is unable to hold such heavy branches)
(I don’t know how to add pictures to show you what it looks like right now but imagine about a 5 foot tall tree with branches that are growing from about 3 1/2 feet tall and outward up to 2.5-3 feet, almost reaching the ground in length. All of the new growth is very long, but I’m not getting a lot of height to support it.

Welcome to Gardening.Stackexchange.  I've rewritten your question so it is easier to read and conforms better to our standards.  Please feel free to edit it further if I've removed any important bits.

You may still want to edit the post and add a picture.  To do this, at the top of the editing window you will see Icons for bolding, underlining etc.  Click on the 6th icon which looks like a moon above 2 mountains.   This should allow you to upload the photo from your device.
